# C++ Read every second line from a text file and safe in vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am doing a small "translator" project. I have this text file which looks like this:

```
friend
amigo
mother
madre
telephone
teléfono
```

As you can see the first line is the English word and the following is the word to translate. I want to save every English word in a vector and every Spanish word into another vector. My problem is that I don't know exactly how to skip these lines.

Comment: Please post what you've tried to do, and what isn't working in it.

Comment: "So i want to safe every english word in a vector and every spanish word into another vector." - what? Did you mean "save" where you wrote "safe"?

Comment: Why vector? Use instead std::map which is a better choice for a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

The vector is not your best choice. Use `std::map` which is really good for a dictionary because elements in it are ordered and unique which is really good choice rather than using two vectors separating words from their definitions:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::map<std::string, std::string> content;
    std::ifstream in("Data.txt");
    std::string word, definition;

    while (std::getline(in, word) && std::getline(in, definition))
        content[word] = definition;

    for (const auto& p : content)
        std::cout << p.first << " : "
        << p.second << std::endl;
     std::cout << std::endl;

    // To search for a word in dictionary:
    std::string search = "mother";
    auto ret = content.find(search);
    if (ret != content.cend())
        std::cout << search << " : \n" <<
        ret->second << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << search << " : was not found in dictionary!" << std::endl;


    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is good, but `std::getline(in, definition);` can fail if there's an odd number of lines in the file, giving you bad data in `content`. Instead I'd make the while into: `while (std::getline(in, word) && std::getline(in, definition)) { content[word] = definition; }`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your intentions are or what you have tried. But I hope this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    string array[10] = {"friend", "amigo", "mother", "madre", "telephone", "teléfono"};
    vector<string> englishWords;
    vector<string> spanishWords;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2){
        englishWords.push_back(array[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i+=2){
        spanishWords.push_back(array[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < englishWords.size(); i++){
        cout << englishWords[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < spanishWords.size(); i++){
        cout << spanishWords[i] << endl;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I don't know exactly how to skip these lines.

Here's an idea: assuming that you always have an English and a Spanish word(or line) occurring alternatively in the file, you can keep a boolean variable `is_english` to denote the language of the current word(or line). It's set to `true` initially, assuming that the first word(or line) is in English, and then set to `false`, `true`, `false`, etc. alternatively, each time you read a new word(or line). In every iteration, if `is_english` is `true`, you append the current word(or line) to `English` vector. Otherwise, append to `Spanish` vector. The code is given below for your reference.

Assuming you have a file like this:

```
friend
amigo
mother
madre
telephone
teléfono
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::ifstream in("./input.txt");
    if(!in){
        std::cout<<"Error opening the file! Maybe the file does not exist!";
        return 0;
    }
    std::string one_line;
    std::vector<std::string> english, spanish;
    bool is_english = true; // Variable to denote current word (starts with english)
    while(in.eof()==0){ // Read until end of file
        getline(in,one_line);
        if(is_english) // If english
            english.push_back(one_line);
        else // Otherwise, spanish
            spanish.push_back(one_line);
        is_english = !is_english; // Flip boolean variable value
    }
    std::cout<<"English words:\n";
    for(const auto i:english)
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\nSpanish words:\n";
    for(const auto i:spanish)
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output

```
English words:
friend
mother
telephone

Spanish words:
amigo
madre
teléfono
```

Comment: thanks that helped alot ! But how am I supposed to compare these two words with eachother? So it should randomly ask for a word (this part i already have) and then the user should write the translation of this word. Then the program should say if its correct or not. Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want a mapping between English and Spanish words so that you can get a word given its corresponding translation, then `vector` isn't the best choice of data structure for that because time complexity would be more in such an approach. Use `map` approach as given in @Maestro's answer.

Comment: However, there's an efficient approach with `vector` too. Let's say you have `N` words in English and Spanish vectors each. For any given `i`(`0<=i<=N-1`), `english[i]` and `spanish[i]` are the translations of each other. So all you have to do is, select a random number `i` from `0` to `N-1`(for randomly selecting a word) and then you have the selected word translation in both languages! (`english[i]` and `spanish[i]`)